# Remote postgres connection getting timout after 10 to 15 minutes

Tags: java, postgresql, connection

I am having a problem with my large old java EE application. I am using below technologies.

Java 1.5,
Jboss 4.0.3,
Postgresql 8.2

The problem is when I run large queries (which runs more than 20 mins) after 10-15 mins the DB connection getting dropped. I am using postgresql-DS data source connection pooling. Error is,

> An I/O error occured while sending to the backend

This happens while I am iterating the results set. I have set below setting as well to the DS.

> idle-timeout-minutes

Any idea about this issue. My application and DB servers are in different cloud servers and accessing through LAN.

Comment: idle-timeout-minutes  default value is  15 minutes. That's why auto close over 15 minutes. So set idle-timeout-minutes to 0.

Comment: I have set idle-timeout-minutes to 0. But still the problem exists

Comment: So can you try to configure tcp_keepalives_idle and tcp_keepalives_interval in your postgre https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: The problem is *not* in PostgreSQL (neither the client nor the server ever drop a connection on which a query is working), so setting PostgreSQL parameters won't affect the problem. If anything, they might help getting the error sooner, because dropped connections are detected earlier.

Comment: Yes. I tried tcp_keepalives_idle and tcp_keepalives_interval but no luck. Anyone came across a problem like this? Appreciate your support on this. Thanks.